# Fragment calling onDestroyView but reference to adapter is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-java

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void my.app.ui.fragment.adapter.IssueAdapter.setOnKeyListener(my.app.fragment.adapter.IssueAdapter$OnItemListener)' on a null object reference
    at MyFragment.onDestroyView(MyFragment.java:429)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:2565)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1512)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:792)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

In Fragment below the `onCreateView` will start an Observable timer where when it reaches 3 seconds the adapter `issueAdapter` will be instantiated. And then when `onDestroyView` is called, it will do some cleanups (setting issueAdapter.setOnKeyListener to null, for example)

Programatically the fragment should only be destroyed after 30 seconds (leaving time to issuesAdapter be instantiated). This is the first time I received that exception in maybe a year of production.

My question is, is that possible I'm missing some lifecycle aware code handler?

Obs.: The device don't allow rotation.

```
private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
private IssueAdapter issueAdapter;    

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(my_fragment, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    disposables.add(
            Observable
                    .timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(__ -> {
                        List<Issue> issues = AppRepository.getInstance().getIssues();
                        issueAdapter = new IssueAdapter(issues);
                        issueAdapter.setOnKeyListener(position -> {
                            this.issueSelected = issues.get(position);
                        });
                    }, ErrorService::notify)
    );

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    issueAdapter.setOnKeyListener(null);
    unbinder.unbind();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    disposables.clear();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Rotation is not the only configuration change that could possibly trigger your Fragment's destruction and re-creation. Additionally, the Fragment could be destroyed even without a configuration change; perhaps the user opened this screen and then immediately received a phone call, and their device killed your app's process to conserve resources.

All in all, even if you think `onDestroyView()` "shouldn't" be called before the three seconds are up, you still need to handle the fact that it can be.

Seems simple enough in this case: just check if `issueAdapter` is null before you try to null out its key listener.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make a safety condition to adapter, because the object exist when all process was success but in error case issueAdapter was a null because not found instance. I recommend you in your onDestroy put

```
if(issueAdapter!=null){
   issueAdapter.setOnKeyListener(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ben P. says, a null check would be the simplist solution.  If you need to be sure that your issueAdapter isn't being cleared, you could add the following line to your OnCreate method in your fragment.

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

This will make sure the same instance (with instance variables) is used if the fragment is recreated.  If you don't need to ensure that your issueHandler does not get set to null, I would avoid using it though.

Comment: `setRetainInstance()` will stop the Fragment from being destroyed and recreated when the activity is destroyed and recreated (instead the fragment will just detach and reattach), but it won't stop the Fragment from being destroyed for other reasons (like the process being killed by the OS).